# What's a good workflow for separating projects from subprojects in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I often find that, using an agenda in block-mode, that my tasks (which are smaller bits of work) are mixed in with my projects (which are larger chunks.) I've wondered if there was a way for a block agenda to list my TODO projects in one block and my tasks (subprojects) in another block.

I've tried using the :PROJECT: tag. The problem is that when I do a regexp for everything that *doesn't* have a :PROJECT: tag I get things that I also don't want (like deadlines that shouldn't yet show up in the agenda, for example.)

One could define a PROJ state but that seems inelegant -- because it's not exactly a state, but a label. A "project" tag (or property) seems more appropriate.

I'm open to any ideas and I hope this helps other people who may have had the same question.

Comment: How about providing us with a sample master todo list, and a proposed `*Org Agenda*` buffer (i.e., a desired result) instead of asking for broad suggestions of how to better organize an undefined workflow?  That way, there will be an answer that everyone can agree is correct -- i.e., we can all take the sample data in the question and verify that the answer produces the desired result.

Comment: How do you distinguish between TODOs and tasks? Are tasks just headlines without a TODO keyword? You can create a custom agenda that only includes TODOs, maybe that helps?

Comment: Could you try to narrow down the question a bit?  It's not clear yet what you want to do, and so the question is a little too open-ended for this site to be helpful.  Once you make the question more precise, we can reopen it.